# After Effect : How can I easily remove "oily or/and shiny skin" with some effects?

Tags: adobe, photoshop, after-effects, adobe-premiere

I have a video in this style:

[image]

I would like to know if there is an efficient way to remove that oily/shiny skin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For info, I found the solution with that plug in (Digital Beauty Box) with the oily. Have to find how to use it to eliminate with more efficiency the shiny, but I think it will be okay => [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u83cLv3V_II)